# Fm receiver circuit doubt

Tags: rf, radio, receiver, frequency-modulation

I was trying to simulate an FM receiver circuit on LTSpice.

The circuit is given on this [website](https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/simple-fm-receiver)

I want to know how the correct current/voltage will look around the speaker (modelled as 8-ohm resistor.)

I have been getting a very weird waveform.

Waveform:

[image]

Circuit:

[image]

ASC contents

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 2044 680
WIRE 80 -272 -32 -272
WIRE 272 -272 80 -272
WIRE 352 -272 272 -272
WIRE 480 -272 432 -272
WIRE 592 -272 480 -272
WIRE 672 -272 592 -272
WIRE 1184 -272 752 -272
WIRE 1696 -272 1184 -272
WIRE 1840 -272 1696 -272
WIRE 480 -240 480 -272
WIRE 592 -240 592 -272
WIRE 480 -144 480 -176
WIRE 544 -144 480 -144
WIRE 592 -144 592 -176
WIRE 592 -144 544 -144
WIRE 80 -128 80 -272
WIRE 544 -112 544 -144
WIRE 1184 -96 1184 -272
WIRE 1280 -96 1184 -96
WIRE 1056 -64 1056 -128
WIRE 272 -48 272 -272
WIRE 352 -48 272 -48
WIRE 512 -48 416 -48
WIRE 672 -48 592 -48
WIRE 784 -48 672 -48
WIRE 960 -48 848 -48
WIRE 1120 -48 1120 -128
WIRE 1184 -32 1184 -96
WIRE 272 -16 272 -48
WIRE 1248 -16 1232 -16
WIRE 1392 -16 1248 -16
WIRE 1456 -16 1392 -16
WIRE 1552 -16 1520 -16
WIRE 1840 -16 1840 -272
WIRE 960 16 912 16
WIRE 80 32 80 -48
WIRE 208 32 80 32
WIRE 784 48 784 -48
WIRE 848 48 848 -48
WIRE 848 48 784 48
WIRE 1392 64 1392 -16
WIRE 1696 64 1696 -272
WIRE 672 80 672 -48
WIRE 784 80 784 48
WIRE 80 112 80 32
WIRE 1552 112 1552 -16
WIRE 1280 128 1280 -96
WIRE 1056 144 1056 32
WIRE -144 160 -144 0
WIRE -32 160 -32 -272
WIRE -32 160 -144 160
WIRE 16 160 -32 160
WIRE 1392 192 1392 128
WIRE -32 224 -32 160
WIRE -32 336 -32 288
WIRE 80 336 80 208
WIRE 80 336 -32 336
WIRE 272 336 272 80
WIRE 272 336 80 336
WIRE 528 336 272 336
WIRE 672 336 672 144
WIRE 672 336 528 336
WIRE 784 336 784 160
WIRE 784 336 672 336
WIRE 912 336 912 16
WIRE 912 336 784 336
WIRE 1056 336 1056 208
WIRE 1056 336 912 336
WIRE 1120 336 1120 16
WIRE 1120 336 1056 336
WIRE 1280 336 1280 192
WIRE 1280 336 1120 336
WIRE 1392 336 1392 272
WIRE 1392 336 1280 336
WIRE 1552 336 1552 192
WIRE 1552 336 1392 336
WIRE 1696 336 1696 128
WIRE 1696 336 1552 336
WIRE 1840 336 1840 64
WIRE 1840 336 1696 336
WIRE 528 400 528 336
FLAG 544 -112 0
FLAG -144 -80 0
FLAG 528 400 0
SYMBOL cap -48 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName VC
SYMATTR Value 22p
SYMBOL npn 16 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value Q2N3707
SYMBOL ind 64 -144 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 2.21p
SYMBOL res 448 -288 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 464 -240 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMBOL polcap 576 -240 R0
SYMATTR InstName C10
SYMATTR Value 100µ
SYMBOL cap 352 -32 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 220n
SYMBOL res 608 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 656 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 2.2n
SYMBOL res 768 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName VR
SYMATTR Value 22k
SYMBOL res 768 -288 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL npn 208 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q2
SYMATTR Value Q2N3707
SYMBOL AutoGenerated\\LM386 1024 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL polcap 1120 -144 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 10µ
SYMBOL polcap 1040 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 10µ
SYMBOL cap 1264 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value 100µ
SYMBOL res 1376 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL cap 1376 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName C7
SYMATTR Value 47n
SYMBOL polcap 1456 0 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C8
SYMATTR Value 220µ
SYMBOL res 1536 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName Speaker
SYMATTR Value 8
SYMBOL polcap 1680 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName C9
SYMATTR Value 100µ
SYMBOL voltage 1840 -32 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 9
SYMBOL voltage -144 16 R180
WINDOW 0 24 96 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 16 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value SFFM(0 1 100000000)
TEXT -416 424 Left 2 !.tran 1000u
TEXT 984 -400 Left 2 !.model Q2N3707  NPN(Is=5.911f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=62.37 Bf=535.1 Ne=1.311\n+  
                             Ise=5.911f Ikf=13.31m Xtb=1.5 Br=1.321 Nc=2 Isc=0 Ikr=0 Rc=1.61\n+   
                            Cjc=4.017p Mjc=.3174 Vjc=.75 Fc=.5 Cje=4.973p Mje=.4146 Vje=.75\n+                               
Tr=4.708n Tf=819.6p Itf=.35 Vtf=4 Xtf=7 Rb=10)
```

Comment: 1. Random circuits from random websites: probably not a good idea. 2. I feel like we've talked about this before, but: the larger right part of your circuit is just an audio amplifier and has nothing to do with the FM demodulation. Focus your simulation on the important part first. Simulation is not a substitute for understanding!

Comment: Pursuant to what @MarcusMüller has said -- if you want to know about the radio part, delete everything between C10 (and R2) and V1 (keep those three components), and simulate that.  If you want to know about the audio circuit, delete everything to the left of C1 and C3 (keep those two), and simulate that (with input into C1).

Comment: You can't inject the signal from V2 in that fashion - it will prevent its correct operation. It may not be possible to simulate this type of locked-oscillator demodulator using SPICE anyway. It is challenging to simulate oscillators with SPICE with normal circuits, your chance of success with this is very low.